# Python - scraping data when clicking a link does not change the URL

Tags: python, python-2.7, web-scraping

I would like to scrape data from here:
http://finance.yahoo.com/stock-center/
In that page there is a section titled "Market Movers", and under that there are 3 columns: "Most Actives", "% Gainers", "% Losers", each of them are clickable.
There is a list of 10 stocks in that section. Also at the end of the 10th stock there is a clickable rectangle "Load 10 more".

What I would like to do is to click on "% Gainers", also click on "Load 10 more", to see a list of top 20 Gainers and scrape the data in Python. However, after these two clicks the URL is the same as before.

I appreciate any help on this.

Comment: So what have you tried so far? Any code to share?

Answer (score 3):

This is dynamic html generation, which is done via some javascript file. A typical scraper (beautifulsoup4, scrapy) won't pick this up, because it only loads the initial. You're going to need to use a web driver, like Selenium. It simulates a user click, which is great because it calls the javascript file, and generates the necessary html. Then you can use something like beautifulsoup4 to pick it up and grab it.

Info on Selenium here: http://www.seleniumhq.org/projects/webdriver/ and http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/py/index.html

Googling "python selenium web scraping" yields a plethora of blogs and tutorials to help you get started.

Comment: Thanks Ivan, I have heard of selenium, but I thought there might be a much easier way to do this.

Comment: Surprisingly, installing and running selenium is easier than you think!

Comment: No, I wouldn't see why there would be something easier.  The next 10 rows stuff is fetched by a javascript ajax call, and as stated by Ivan, used to inject/update html.  The javascript ajax call is clearly a browser-type activity, not something that a simple Python url read would be carrying out.  Therefore, you need a "proper browser" to carry out this work and that gets you to Selenium.  If you were coding in javascript rather than Python, there are similar things like headless (invisible) browsers a la PhantomJS to deal with same issue - you need to fire javascript code, not just read urls